Failed to transform *****.aar to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.status=release}. > Could not find ****.aar
enter image description here

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:yunpanDebugCompileClasspath'.
Failed to transform logging-interceptor-4.10.0.aar (com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Could not find logging-interceptor-4.10.0.aar (com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0).
Searched in the following locations:
epo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/logging-interceptor/4.10.0/logging-interceptor-4.10.0.aar
Failed to transform retrofit-2.9.0.aar (com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Could not find retrofit-2.9.0.aar (com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0).
Searched in the following locations:
epo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/retrofit2/retrofit/2.9.0/retrofit-2.9.0.aar
Failed to transform okhttp-4.10.0.aar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Could not find okhttp-4.10.0.aar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0).
Searched in the following locations:
epo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/4.10.0/okhttp-4.10.0.aar
Failed to transform orange-1.6.1.2.aar (com.taobao.android:orange:1.6.1.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Could not find orange-1.6.1.2.aar (com.taobao.android:orange:1.6.1.2).
Searched in the following locations:
https://mvnrepo.alibaba-inc.com/mvn/repository/com/taobao/android/orange/1.6.1.2/orange-1.6.1.2.aar
Failed to transform fastjson-1.2.75.aar (com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.75) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Could not find fastjson-1.2.75.aar (com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.75).
Searched in the following locations:
epo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/alibaba/fastjson/1.2.75/fastjson-1.2.75.aar
Failed to transform accs_sdk_taobao-3.4.5.6-fix3.aar (com.taobao.android:accs_sdk_taobao:3.4.5.6-fix3) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Could not find accs_sdk_taobao-3.4.5.6-fix3.aar (com.taobao.android:accs_sdk_taobao:3.4.5.6-fix3).
Searched in the following locations:
https://mvnrepo.alibaba-inc.com/mvn/repository/com/taobao/android/accs_sdk_taobao/3.4.5.6-fix3/accs_sdk_taobao-3.4.5.6-fix3.aar
Failed to transform networksdk-3.5.16.31.aar (com.taobao.android:networksdk:3.5.16.31) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Could not find networksdk-3.5.16.31.aar (com.taobao.android:networksdk:3.5.16.31).
Searched in the following locations:
https://mvnrepo.alibaba-inc.com/mvn/repository/com/taobao/android/networksdk/3.5.16.31/networksdk-3.5.16.31.aar
Failed to transform aranger-1.4.6.aar (com.taobao.android:aranger:1.4.6) to match attributes {artifactType=android-databinding, org.gradle.status=release}.
> Could not find aranger-1.4.6.aar (com.taobao.android:aranger:1.4.6).

This error occurred when I changed a module common from source code reference to aar reference, the network can normally access the major warehouses。please help to look at it, thank you
distributionUrl=http://mtl-gradle-mirror.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip


classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"

The common module is configured with:
 compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [screenOrientation: rootProject.ext.screenOrientation]
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/coroutines.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

I can't find the reason why it's really wrong and have tried demoting gradle
